# Use object identities when using QUnit.deepEqual() on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, qunit, object-identity

Situation is as follows: I want to test a function of mine, which returns an array of objects. The objects have no enumerable properties, but are taken from a common cache/store.

In my testcases I now want to test, whether the contents of the returned array are correct. So I assumed, that `deepEqual()` would be the function to use, but the tests actually return this (reduced the testcase a little):

```
QUnit.test( "array of objects", function( assert ) {

    // create two objects
  var o1 = new Obj( 1 ),
      o2 = new Obj( 2 );

  // compare objects themselves
  assert.notEqual( o1, o2, 'different objects' ); // success

  // compare identical arrays 
  assert.deepEqual( [ o1 ], [ o1 ], 'identical arrays - deepEqual' ); // success

  // compare different arrays
  assert.notDeepEqual( [ o1 ], [ o2 ], 'different arrays - deepEqual' ); // fail

});

// some sample object
function Obj(){}
```

[Fiddle for the testcase](https://jsfiddle.net/sirko/9uhcrepz/)

(I also tested `propEqual()` to see, if that one works here.)

So QUnit recognizes the two objects as different (see first test), but fails to recognize the difference as soon as I use the array.

So I played around a little and as soon as I have an enumerable property on my object, in which both instances differ, QUnit will recognize it: [Changed Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sirko/9uhcrepz/1/)

```
function Obj( val ){ this._val = val; }
```

Interesting enough, if the enumerable property is set to the same value by using this:

```
var o1 = new Obj( 1 ),
    o2 = new Obj( 1 );
```

I see the same behavior as with no property ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sirko/9uhcrepz/2/)).

So, with the above examples in mind,

**How do I force QUnit to compare two objects by identity in order to check the contents of an array?**

as per discussion with @Ilya here a rephrase of the actual question:

**How can I use `deepEqual()` just for one level - meaning, all elements of the given array should be compared by object identity?**

PS: I know the naive solution would be to compare element by element in the array, but I think there should be a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I force QUnit to compare two objects by identity in order to
>   check the contents of an array?

If you want to test that `t1 = [ o1, o2 ]` and `t2 = [ o1, o2 ]` are different objects, equal does exactly that.

Conversely, if you want to test that `t1 = [ o1, o2 ]` and `t2 = [ o1, o2 ]` are equal, you would have to create a custom assertion specifically for the array-containing-the-same-objects case.

`deepEqual` evaluates (recursively) the properties of the objects, what else could it do ?

Comment: I want to test that `[ o1 ]` is not equal to `[ o2 ]`, but `t1 = [ o1 ]` and `t2 = [ o1 ] ` are.

Comment: `assert.equal( [o1], [o1], '' )` fails for the same reason that `assert.equal( o1, o2, '' )` fails: same properties, but different objects. Seems consistent to me.

Comment: ok, fair point, removed that sentence from the question, but the overall problem remains the same. Inside the array I want just to compare by object identities, call it a "`deepEqual`-one-level-deep" variant.

Comment: I'lm afraid you would have to create your own assert for that (`arrayEqual` ?)